# Which Canonical Link is correct

Tags: amp-html

In case of a single page AMP only website which is the correct "canonical" for the index.html

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/index.html">

<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/">

<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your url is canonical its does not depend on index.html, index.php or else ...

If you only have one page, and that page is an AMP page than your canonical link is

Url : https://www.example.com/

Canonical Link : `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/">`